# Powershell MySQL full path

Tags: mysql, powershell, replace, escaping, unc

Im trying to insert a full directory path into MySQL from a Powershell script. The connection and insert work great but i'm hitting a snag with the readability of the filepath. I've looked around online for some time and can't find anyone with this exact problem: Either powershell or mysql is dropping the \ (backslash) characters from the file path variable on insert. In the console they appear fine as objects so I am think this is SQL related? Im not finding a whole lot about escaping on insert which just loops me back to powershell replacing (which does not work work either.

I know how to escape and replace characters IF I know where they are going to be but how do I escape baackslashes that appear in different parts of the file path?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use prepared statements—e.g. see https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/wgwcj/what_is_the_best_way_to_escape_input_content_for/c5guih9

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I achieved this by using a -split operator in PS. After I split the file path at all the backslashes I just built a string to cat my variable back together. Hacky...but it works. :) The var $RemoteName inserts into the DB as \\path1\path2$

```
           $shared = gwmi Win32_NetworkConnection -ComputerName $hostname | select LocalName,RemoteName
                foreach($sharemap in $shared){
                    $localname = $sharemap.LocalName
                    $RemoteName_nonstring = $sharemap.RemoteName
                    $RemoteName = $RemoteName_nonstring
                    $file = $RemoteName.Split("\")

                        $b = $file[2]
                        $c = $file[3]

                        $RemoteName = "\\\\$b\\$c$"
```

Thanks for the sugestions and if anyone has a more efficient way im all ears...